# What is the next number in the series 1111111,111,21,13,12,11,10?

Tags: number-sequence

Find the next number in the series 1111111,111,21,13,12,11,10,

[There was a hint saying the answer is a single-digit integer, and the series has something to do with the number 7]

I've only been able to find that if you do ones place+ 2tens place+4hundreds place...., apart from the first number, we get 7,5,4,3,2.

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Where is this problem from?

Comment: It is a variation on a classical problem.

Comment: More specifically, where did you get the problem from? Someone gave you a hint; who was that?

Comment: I wonder why an (apparently correct) answer was deleted. If it was correct, the first controversial term $1111111$ is covered by [SE Maths](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371972/what-would-base-1-be) question.

Comment: The question was first asked on Mathematics Stack Exchange but seems deleted now there (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4554917/what-is-the-next-number-in-the-series-1111111-111-21-13-12-11-10)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next number is:

> 7

The reasoning is as follows:

> Each entry is a representation of 7 in a different base.
>  Seven 1's in a row is "base 1" for 7. Each digit just counts 1.
>  111 is binary for 7. One 4, one 2, and one 1.
>  21 is base 3. Two 3's and one 1.
>  13 is base 4. One 4 and three 1's.
>  12 is base 5. One 5 and two 1's.
>  11 is base 6. One 6 and one 1's.
>  10 is base 7. One 7 and zero 1's.
>  So the next is base 8, and in that it is just seven 1's, or 7.

Comment: Please do not answer questions which are off-topic per our [attribution policy](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide); that policy is in place to prevent cheating and plagiarism.

Comment: @bobble Hum... I do not see even a single close vote.

Comment: There are currently 4 close votes, you just do not have enough rep to see them.

Comment: @bobble Hard to comply with a thing that the operating system explicitly hides from me.

Comment: I'm not attacking you, simply informing you of the site policy. It was an attempt to be helpful.

Comment: @BillOnne you can take a look at the comments on the question, or interpret bobble's first comment as your indication that the question is off topic.